# ui router - Passing data from controller to another view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

Without injecting services how to pass data from one view's controller to another view. I refered data,params, resolve, parent-child concepts but I am not able to figured it out.

Here is the example:

**Routing:**

```
  $stateProvider
    .state('route1', {
      url: "/route1",
      templateUrl: "route1.html",
      controller: "firstCtrl"
    })
    .state('route2', {
      url: "/route2",
      templateUrl: "route2.html",
      controller: "secondCtrl"
    })
```

**Views:**

**route1.html**

```
 view 1 : {{firstCtrlValue}}
```

**route2.html**

```
 View 2: <input type="text" ng-model="firstCtrlValue"/>  <!-- Of course, It won't work -->
 <a ui-sref="route1">go to route 1</a>
 <a ui-sref="route2">go to route 2</a>
```

**Controllers:**

```
.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.firstCtrlValue = "I am from first";
})
.controller('secondCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.secondCtrlValue = "Hey I'm from 2nd Ctrl";
});
```

What I want: If i change the model value from route2 it must affect route1.

Here is the [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/W3PdouBW3dvpNIEATmGo?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

I see two ways of getting this done:

1. Use `localCache` or `sessionCache` in your browser for saving/retrieving the data that both views need. There is a very nice angular plugin for doing this [here](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage). Every controller updates/retrieves the data through the cache.
2. Create a custom `service` in your app that has APIs for saving and retrieving the data. Whenever a new value is stored in the service, then use `$rootScope.$broadcast()` to notify the other controller of the changes so it can fetch the new value.

If neither of these two approaches is what you want, you can try to put a `resolve {}` block in your state config like the following:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('route1', {
      url: "/route1",
      templateUrl: "route1.html",
      controller: "firstCtrl",
      resolve: {
         DataService: 'DataService',
         dataObj: function(DataService) {
            return DataService.getDataObj(); // a promise (e.g. return $http.get(url)) 
         }
      }
    })
```

Then in your controller `firstCtrl`, you need to inject the `dataObj`:

```
function firstCtrl($scope, dataObj) {
  //TODO: use dataObj as a value or object however you want
}
```

In your `DataService`, you need to make sure the function `getDataObj()` returns a promise though, example:

```
function getDataObj() {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  deferred.solve({key: "value..."});
  return deferred.promise; //can also be return $http.get(url) of that sort
}
```

Comment: This will resolve data from some http call before entering into firstctrl. Right ? I want to resolve the firstctrl's value before entering into another view (say route2)

Comment: yes, your understanding is right. If you want to use the `resolve{}` block in each state, it is specific to that state's controller. I don't think it can resolve data for another controller, and it does not make sense IMHO. Why would a controller resolve data for another controller? can you *always predict* another controller will use that data?

Comment: It may not be. But let assume I have 1000 records. I have two views say list view and edit view. Each have its own controller. Edit view wants data from the list which is selected from the list view and whatever change I made in the edit view must reflect back into list. How can I achieve that ? Shouldn't I use different controller ?